# How to create linear gradient with background mask in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

[image: Goal]

I would like to recreate this chart color scheme in Chart.js.
So far I've succeeded in creating the horizontal linear gradient for both the stroke and background colors, but I can't find a way to create the opacity mask for the background color to 'blend' it into the page background.

This is my chart so far
[image: My chart]

*Note:*
I can create an opacity mask on the canvas itself using css property:

`-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 50%, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)))`

But this method masks the whole lower bottom of the chart, i.e the stroke of the chart, for example

[image: Using css]

How would I go about masking only the background color of the chart?

**Chart.js setup**

```
data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      fill: true,
      data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
      borderColor: getGradient,
      pointBorderColor: getGradient,
      pointBackgroundColor: getGradient,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: getGradient,
      pointHoverBorderColor: getGradient,
      backgroundColor: getGradient
    },
  ]
};

let width, height, gradient;
function gradient(ctx, chartArea) {
  const chartWidth = chartArea.right - chartArea.left;
  const chartHeight = chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top;
  if (!gradient || width !== chartWidth || height !== chartHeight) {
    // Create the gradient because this is either the first render
    // or the size of the chart has changed
    width = chartWidth;
    height = chartHeight;
    var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(chartArea.right, chartArea.top, chartArea.left, chartArea.top);
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, "#80b6f4");
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, "#f49080");
  }

  return gradientStroke;
}

function getGradient(context) {
  const chart = context.chart;
  const {ctx, chartArea} = chart;

  if (!chartArea) {
    // This case happens on initial chart load
    return;
  }
  return gradient(ctx, chartArea);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have solved that by now. In any case, I think you should try to change the values you pass to [createLinearGradient function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient). See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/bLk48zyo/7/) (it's not mine, but helped me to understand that).

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d"); 

/*** Gradient ***/
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(250,174,50,1)');   
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(250,174,50,0)');
/***************/

var data = {
            labels : ["02:00","04:00","06:00","08:00","10:00","12:00","14:00","16:00","18:00","20:00","22:00","00:00"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    fillColor : gradient, // Put the gradient here as a fill color
                    strokeColor : "#ff6c23",
                    pointColor : "#fff",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#ff6c23",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "#ff6c23",
                    data : [25.0,32.4,22.2,39.4,34.2,22.0,23.2,24.1,20.0,18.4,19.1,17.4]
                }
            ]
        };

        var options = {
            responsive: true,
            datasetStrokeWidth : 3,
            pointDotStrokeWidth : 4,
            tooltipFillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",
            tooltipFontStyle: "bold",
            tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label + ' hod' %>: <%}%><%= value + '°C' %>",
            scaleLabel : "<%= Number(value).toFixed(0).replace('.', ',') + '°C'%>"
        };

        


        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

```html
<canvas id="chart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, the work around that I've eventually found was to create two graphs with the same data. One that only displays the stroke and one that only displays the background, with their respective gradients, then using position: absolute, I positioned the 'stroke graph' over the 'background graph' and got the results I was looking for